# How to use Angular Material with VS2017 SPA Templates

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I'm building an Angular2 app using the SPA templates and JavaScriptServices provided by Microsoft (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/).

I'd like to use Angular Material as opposed to Bootstrap for styling/themeing, however I'm unable to get it to work.

Following the setup guide (https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) is straightforward enough, however when it comes to including the theme assets (@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/...) from the npm package in the wwwroot dist output to make them available to the app I'm at a complete loss.

I assume it's simply a case of modifying the WebPack configuration, however after an hour or two of tinkering and google searches I'm no closer to understanding what to do.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

NB. Please don't suggest copying the files I need to the wwwroot or linking to a CDN etc.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1189201/Adding-Angular-Material-in-ASP-NET-Core-Angular-SP Does this help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've possibly found a more complete/comprehensive way to achieve this...

1. Close your Visual Studio solution
2. Open the project folder and delete the `node_modules` directory
3. Open up a command prompt for the project directory
4. Run `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk` in command prompt
5. Run `npm install --save @angular/animations` in command prompt
6. Upgrade the `@angular` and `rxjs` packages to the latest/compatible versions in `package.json`. This is a headache. I have no idea which are the right versions and which are wrong!
7. Run `npm install` in command prompt
8. Update `webpack.config.vendor.js`, adding the following two values

   ```
   const nonTreeShakableModules = [
       ...
       '@angular/material',
       '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'
   ];
   ```
9. Run `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` in command prompt
10. Open the solution in Visual Studio
11. Build the solution, after which you should be able to use it, having followed the "Getting Started" guide at https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

I've checked in a vaguely working version to GitHub - it can be found at https://github.com/alterius/AngularMaterial2DotNetCoreSPA

Comment: I’m curious, how is the above different?

Comment: @spottedmahn it's complete and comprehensive. I had to fill in the gaps with your answer which was a headache. I've also included a link to a working template on GitHub with the work done.

Answer (score 6):

In `webpack.config.vendor.js` add the following two entries:

```
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    ...
    "@angular/material",
    "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
];
```

Re-run webpack via:

`webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`

---

[**Source**: Adding Angular Material in ASP.NET Core Angular SPA Template by Fiyaz Hasan](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1189201/Adding-Angular-Material-in-ASP-NET-Core-Angular-SP)

Answer (score 0):

There is a new template available now and it is much better than the old template. I also ran into a lot of issues in the old version of template provided by Visual Studio. The new template is available in ASP.Net Core 2.1 by default else you need to follow instructions in below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

If you are looking for a working example with EF Core 2, Angular Material and ASP.Net Core Web API please refer below link

http://hive.rinoy.in/building-a-web-app-using-asp-net-core-2-and-angular5-frameworks/

Comment: this works as a charm with material 5 and the 2.1 template. How to update to angular material 6 ?

Comment: you can do the upgrade with npm command. npm install @angular/cli@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/language-service@latest  @types/jasmine@latest @types
/jasminewd2@latest @types/node@latest --save-dev

Comment: that updates Angular Material to 6 or only Angular to 6?